# Getting value from outside Context Node XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on using XSLT to transform pieces of XML into a Excel Workbook and I have this bit of XML.

```
<RELATORIO>
    <MODULO>
        <NAME>ObtemSocios_P</NAME>
        <VALUES>
          <ROW>
            <DistribuicaoCapital>0</DistribuicaoCapital>
            <Nome>diogo</Nome>
            <PercentagemCapital />
          </ROW>
          <ROW>
            <DistribuicaoCapital>0</DistribuicaoCapital>
            <Nome>ze maria</Nome>
            <PercentagemCapital />
          </ROW>
          <ROW>
            <DistribuicaoCapital>0</DistribuicaoCapital>
            <Nome>Manel</Nome>
            <PercentagemCapital />
          </ROW>
       </VALUES>
    </MODULO>
    <MODULO>
        <NAME>ObtemCapitalSocial_P</NAME>
        <VALUES>
          <ROW>
            <CapitalRegistado>8734652</CapitalRegistado>
          </ROW>
        </VALUES>
      </MODULO>
</RELATORIO>
```

I get inside the MODULO context like this

```
 <xsl:when test="NAME='ObtemSocios_P'">
----
</xsl:when>
```

My question is, how can i get the value from  `<CapitalRegistado>8734652</CapitalRegistado>` when I'm inside the "ObtemSocios_P" MODULO context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible ways, and the right one to choose depends on what else might be in the document when it's not identical to your example. If your xsl:when condition is correct, then your context item is the first MODULO element, and you can get to the second MODULO element using any of the following expressions:

```
following-sibling::MODULO[1]

../MODULO[2]

../MODULO[NAME='ObtemCapitalSocial_P']

//MODULO[NAME='ObtemCapitalSocial_P']
```

From any of these you can then access `VALUES/ROW/CapitalRegistado`.